# Chicken or egg in functions/actors processing WorldState

Tags: functional-programming, erlang, game-engine

I have read the series "Purely Functional Retrogames"

http://prog21.dadgum.com/23.html

It discusses some interesting techniques to build a (semi-)pure game world update loop.

However, I have the following side remark, that I cannot seem to get my head around:

Suppose you have a system, where every enemy, and every player are separate actors, or separate pure functions.

Suppose they all get a "WorldState" as input, and output a New WorldState (or, if you're thinking in actor terms, send the new WorldState to the next actor, ending with for instance a "Game Render" actor).

Then, there's two ways to go with this:

1. Either you start with one actor, (f.i. the player), and feed him the "current world". 
   Then, you feed the new world, to the next enemy, and so on, until all actors have converted the worlds. Then, the last world is the new world you can feed to the render loop. (or, if you followed the above article, you end up with a list of events that have occurred in the world, which can be processed).
2. A second way, is to just give all actors the current WorldState at the same time. They generate any changes, which may conflict (for instance, two enemies and the player can take a coin in the same animation frame) -> it is up to the game system to solve these conflicts by processing the events. By processing all events, the Game actor creates the new world, to be used in the next update frame.

I have a feeling I'm just confronted with the exact same "race condition" problem I wished to avoid by using pure functions with immutable data.

Any advice here?

Comment: Parallelism in a game world must be embraced, not fought against by the use of global state. You may find the discussion here relevant: http://zxq9.com/erlmud/html/001-001_architecture.html The most important thing to remember with concurrency is that each actor has its own perspective on the world -- the "global state" can never be completely observed without halting the system to inspect it forensically. This is much the way the real world works, and makes writing simulations in Erlang magnificently more easy to reason about than in a globally-stateful procedural way.

Comment: Your first solution will serialize all the processing of the player processes and remove much of the parallelism while the second one assumes you can have a consistent global state all can access at the same time. Keep the world state in a separate process/set of processes and let the player processes access it when they need to read/save state. This preserves more of the parallelism and is much more scalable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't read the article, but with the coin example you are creating a kind of global variable: you give a copy of the world state to all actors and you suppose that each actor will evaluate the game, take decision and expect that their action will succeed, regardless of the last phase which is the conflict solving. I would not call this a race condition but rather a "blind condition", and yes, this will not work.

I imagine that you came to this solution in order to allow parallelism, not available in solution 1. In my opinion, the problem is about responsibility.

The coin must belong to an actor (a server acting as resource manager) as anything in the application. This actor is the only responsible to decide what will happen to the coin.

All requests (is there something to grab, grab it, drop something...) should be sent to this actor (one actor per cell, or per map, level or any split that make sense for the game).

The way you will manage it is then up to you: serve all requests in the receive order, buffer them until a synchro message comes and make a random decision or priority decision... In any case the server will be able to reply to all actors with success or failure without any risk of race condition since the server process is run (at least in erlang) on a single core and proceed one message at a time.

Comment: Interestingly, each coin can have such a server. The one thing I'm still struggling to understand after your answer is how the system knows all actors have made their move. If all players/enemies act on the same world instance, how would I implement a terminal state? Or do I just make a 'turn' actor that processes end_move messages and rebroadcasts using a remaining_players value that needs to reach 0. Any insight there?

Comment: One server per coin may be extreme :o), mainly because each actor of the game will have to know its pid to communicate with it, but as I said, one per cell may be achievable. The interest is that each process have only few simple things to do. Fast to write, easy to test, and if you use gen_server from OTP, you only have to test the "stateless"  callback functions. If the game is synchronous in the sense that all, or a part, of the actors are asked to play, and then the game progresses, the "turn" actor can do the job. message passing in one VM is efficient, much faster than user interface.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Pascal answer, you can solve parallelization by splitting (i assume huge map) to smaller chunks which depend on last state (or part of it, like an edge) of its neighbours. This allows you to distribute this game among many nodes.

Comment: Yes this is interesting, but I'd do it inversely: splitting up the map in chunks that each depend on the current state, and inside the chunk let each actor depend on the state of the product of a different actor in the chunk?

Comment: @buddhabrot Its hard to tell. It depends on game specific. I think actors shouldn't get entire world but only things that matters for them, then they make a decision within turn time and they send it to chunk_actor. If it is rejected with some reason, then it can make another fast decision or hang on until the next turn. Note that you don't really need actors when it is waiting for WorldState product of previous one (it's not concurrent). You can do the same in chunk main loop without copying WorldState for each actor.